# Can you use your Maaser money on a Bar Mitzvah present?

Tags: maaser-tithes, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, gifts

If you give a Bar Mitzvah boy whose family struggles financially money as his gift, is that considered like you gave Maaser?

Considering that most boys save up their Bar Mitzvah money for when they are older, at which point their financial situation could be completely different, I’m inclined to say it wouldn’t be considered like you gave Maaser. Is that right?

Comment: Not an answer but related http://dinonline.org/2012/02/01/gift-for-orphan-from-maaser-money/

Comment: I would imagine that anything you give extra because of the family's financial condition would be potential Maaser, whereas the amount/gift you're "expected to give as a guest" would not be Maaser.

Comment: @Danny Schoemann That makes a lot of sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

R Yisroel Bronstein, writing in [Halachos of Ma'aser Kesafim](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B00500YM6S/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1), answers your question (p. 123)

> It is permitted to use *maaser* to buy a gift for a poor *chasan*, for
>   a *bar mitzvah* boy whose father is poor, or for a needy family in
>   honor of their son's *bris*. If one would anyway give such a gift from
>   non-*maaser* monies, then the use of *maaser* is forbidden.

He quotes a story of the Steipler Gaon who once bought a *sefer* from a poor author with *maaser* money and gave it as a gift to a *bar mitzvah* boy saying the boy was for sure poor since he didn't have any possession. R Bronstein explicitly mentions this is a unique story and ruling.